# Cassandra docker access from host

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

this is my compose file,I'm binding the Cassandra/container ports but I can't access the Cassandra container with the cqlsh from my Host.

```
version: '2'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.0.12
    ports:
        - 9042:9042
        - 9160:9160
other-services....
```

---

Docker output says:

```
cassandra_1     | INFO  21:00:42 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
```

Ports:

```
$ docker port 00269f36bc54
9042/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9042
9160/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9160
```

1. If I do `cqlsh` in my host machine doesn't connect to cassandra container.
2. If I do a `netstat` command I don't see any entry listening for the port 9042...

Comment: You appear to have lost the start of your explanation... could you edit it back in?

Comment: thanks for the observation